# Locally my app is loading assets from S3 properly with -e production but on Heroku not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3

I have an app which assets are served by S3. When I'm running it locally with **-e production** it's working well, each asset is being loaded **from amazon S3** correctly.

However, on Heroku they aren't. Moreover, they aren't get found because the names of, for example, of `application-....*.css` and `application-....*.js` on heroku is different from the names of the corresponding files on localhost and S3.

On localhost it loads, say:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/aaa/assets/application-aaabbbcccdd.css
```

and this file does exist on S3. But on Heroku it loads:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/aaa/assets/application-eeefffccc.css
```

and it doesn't exist on S3 (**what makes it load the different file?**). It's not forbidden or something, it just doesn't exist.

The same goes for `application-fdsfdsfdsfs.js`

I uploaded the assets to S3 using s3cmd (please don't suggest me to use any gem).

```
cd public
s3cmd sync . s3://......
```

Here's my **production.rb**

```
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket"
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.compile = false
```

What's the matter?

P.S. A few hours ago it somehow was working almost well on Heroku, meaning, it didn't load the files mentioned above properly.